# Join two lists into one list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of the same length. I want to merge them into a list of lists like this example:

```
left_list = [-1,-3,15,3,1.7]
right_list = [1.2,2,17,3.5,2]

res_list = [[-1,1.2],[-3,2],[15,17],[3,3.5],[1.7,2]]
```

notice the `left_list` has smaller valleues so the order matters. Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try `zip`?

Answer (score 0):

pop the items from each list then form tuples and append them to a list

```
left_list = [-1,-3,15,3,1.7]
right_list = [1.2,2,17,3.5,2,4]

new_list=[]
while left_list or right_list:
    
    if len(left_list)>0:
        item1=left_list.pop(0)
    else:
        item1=np.nan
    if len(right_list)>0:
        item2=right_list.pop(0)
    else:
        item2=np.nan
    new_list.append((item1,item2))
    
print(new_list)
```